# Does the 'require' keyword in PHP and Node.JS do the same?

Tags: php, node.js, require

Does the **require** keyword in [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) and in [node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) do the same, means they are both to load the external script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both load code but they are not identical.
PHP's require is quite a bit closer to just substituting the `require` line with the (arbitrary) code it loads while node.js works with modules i.e. variables et al cannot that easily "poison" the namespace of the including code. There's also a distinction between require and require_once in php and on the other side there is node.js's handling of cyclic require chains which is quite different from php's require/require_once mechanism.
And so on and on....